# How to make dependent cy.request calls in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test my *live* web server data responses (e.g. no stubbing/mocking).  I tried using `cy.server()` with `cy.route()`, but since the content type of the response is `application/json` apparently `cy.server()` does not cover this and the cypress error message tells me to use `cy.request()`.

However, I can not use `cy.wait()` with `cy.request()` .  I have to resort to nesting the second `cy.request()` in the callback of the first.  Is there a way to not nest the second `cy.request` inside the callback of the first `cy.request`?

So in this contrived example, I need to grab the `user` data first before making the call to get `book` data.  I could only get this to work by nesting the `book` request within the callback of the `user` request.  I would prefer to use something akin to the `cy.wait()` API instead of nesting.

```
    it(`should get book based on user`, () => {
      cy.request({
        url: `/user`,
      }).as('user');

      cy.get('@user').then((userResp) => {
        const user = userResp.body;

        cy.request({
          url: `/user/${user.id}/book`,
        }).as('userBook');

        cy.get('@userBook').then((userBookResp) => {
          cy.log(userBookResp);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Why can't you use cy.route and cy.wait ? I have amde the same kind of subsequent route with wait, using cy.route and cy.wait.
`cy.route('POST', '**/api/**').as('apiPost.');
cy.wait(1500);
cy.route('GET', '**/api/**').as('apiGet.');
cy.wait(1500);`

Comment: @Shujath hi there!  I tried using `cy.route` but cypress threw an error saying `cy.route` can't be used with `application/json` content type.  It only works with `text/html`.

Comment: I think the solution is to use `cy.route2`, but I haven't verified yet.  Will update if I find out.